# ASP.NET Core 3.1 move localization resource files to a separate project

Tags: c#, .net-core, localization, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to move my localization resource files to a separate project, since in my solution I have my logic split in different projects, and I'd like to share the same resource files on all of them without adding references between each other. I've got familiar with the new .NET Core way of localization and I tested it out in my MVC project and everything worked, however when I created a new .NET Core class library for the resources I couldn't manage to use them. I've read pretty much everything and couldn't manage to find a solution.

Here's my Resources project hierarchy:

[image: resoruces]

I've tried moving the "resx" files to Resources folder, moving them next to Resources.cs without any folders, moving Resources.cs to the Resources folder, nothing works.

Here's my code:

Resources.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

namespace Resources
{
public interface IResources
{
}
public class Resources : IResources
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

    public Resources(IStringLocalizer<Resources> localizer)
    {
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public string this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _localizer[index];
        }
    }
}
}
```

Startup.cs:

Configureservices method:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
        services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(o =>
                {
                    o.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                    {
                        return factory.Create(typeof(Resources.SharedResources));
                    };
                })
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("bg")
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
```

Configure method:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Index.cshtml where I'm trying to load my localization resources:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization; 
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<Resources.Resources> Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">@Localizer["Welcome"]</h1>
    <p>@Localizer["LearnAbout"] <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">@Localizer["Build"]</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Instead of getting the resource values I just get the name of the resource as written inside the @Localizer.

Is there any way to have the resources separated in a different project in .NET Core 3.1? I've seen a lot of answers about older versions, but they don't work in 3.1.

Any help will be appreciated!

Edit: After changing the names of the resource files to SharedResources I can use them in the views, but I can't understand how to use them in ViewModels.
Whenever I call `[Display(ResourceType = typeof(SharedResources), Name = "lblFromDate")]` on my attribute I get an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because
> localization failed. Type 'Resources.SharedResources' is not public or
> does not contain a public static string property with the name
> 'lblFromDate'.

I've made the resource files public, but for some reason they don't generate .cs files. Something that I've noticed is that I actually can't create resource files in .Net 3.1 Class Libraries, even searching for a resource file doesn't show anything up.

Comment: When you check the properties of the .resx file, in the "Custom Tool" do you see the value "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" ?

Comment: Yes it's there. I actually managed to use the display attribute in the model, the only way that it works is if I don't specify ResourceType. I still can't understand if I can have more than just the "SharedResources" files in a different project. I want to build have all my resources in a different project, and simply putting them all inside one file will be a huge mess.